# Java Spring Boot Web App: Handling 404 Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I'm going through a Java Spring Boot tutorial and am in the middle of trying to handle 404 exceptions. I have the exact code as in the tutorial, but for some reason it isn't working, although the 403 error is working. In the tutorial, the way the instructor handles all outstanding exceptions is with the following, specifically defaultErrorHandler(). However, this is not working:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @Value("${message.error.exception}")
    private String exceptionMessage;

    @Value("${message.error.duplicate.user}")
    private String duplicateUserMessage;

    @ExceptionHandler(value=Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", exceptionMessage);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("url", req.getRequestURL());
        modelAndView.getModel().put("exception", e);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.exception");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value=DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ModelAndView duplicateUserHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", duplicateUserMessage);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("url", req.getRequestURL());
        modelAndView.getModel().put("exception", e);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.exception");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

I then tried to add something similar to what the instructor has for handling 403 errors, found below, but this is not working either:

```
    @RequestMapping("/403")
    ModelAndView accessDenied(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        System.out.println("We're here");
        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", accessDeniedMessage);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.message");
        return modelAndView;

    }

    @RequestMapping("/404")
    ModelAndView pageNotFound(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", exceptionMessage);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.message");
        return modelAndView;

    }
```

I've tried to debug by putting System.out.println("test") in each of the suspected methods, but none of them have been reached. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you say `However, this is not working`, what is the error you are getting? Any logs?

Comment: Try with a forced `throw new DataIntegrityViolationException( "Exception forced to happen" )` and see if that is working. See any exceptions are logged. To me `ExceptionHandler` code seem fine

Comment: Sorry for responding late but yes I get the following when trying to go to an unknown url rather than being directed to my custom page handling 404 errors for the user: [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404. I have it set that no matter what the user types in after localhost:8080/, then they will originally be directed to the localhost:8080/login page. However, once logging in, if they type anything after localhost:8080/ that isn't a url of the app, then I mistakenly get the white label error.

Answer (score 0):

If You wanna Handle 404 exception to show your custom page rather than whitelable error.You can do that by creating folder named error in resources directory.In error folder create 404.html file and add html code,style,etc.
Now Spring Boot picks your 404.html file and displays to user whenever 404 error occurs.Like this you can also handle any errors just putting filename of error code 501.html,407.html etc